# How to change field value of sObject in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, sobject, sobjectfield

I need to write the equivalent code in LWC . Here a sObject is defined in aura cmp and then it is assigning  a value to one of its field which is Source__c. CreateCaseActivity is a sObject. How can i write a similar code in LWC without calling apex method and then pass this sObject to a different method .

```
 upload: function(component, docIds) {
        var action = component.get("c.saveFileUploaded"); 
        var Comment = component.find("mytextarea").get('v.value');
        var RecordID = component.get('v.recordId');
        var isMobile = component.get("v.displayMobileVersion");
        if(isMobile){
            component.set('v.CreateCaseActivity.Source__c', component.get('v.cspMobile'));
        } 
        else {
            component.set('v.CreateCaseActivity.Source__c', component.get('v.cspWeb'));
        }
        action.setParams({ 
            'documentIds': docIds,
            'comments': Comment,
            'rcdId': RecordID,
            'ipName' : component.get("v.CreateCaseActivity")
            }); 
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) { 
            var state = a.getState();
            if (state === "ERROR"){
                 var errors = a.getError();
                confirm(errors[0].message);
                console.log(errors);
            }
           //if Success display Toast
            //Bug:1352930 - removed Toast Nessage. 
            if (state === "SUCCESS") { 
                
            } 
$A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

I tried declaring the object in lwc and change the field value similarly but it is not working.

LWC version here for reference:

```
uploadFiles(docIds) { 
    let CreateCaseActivity = { 'sobjectType': 'Case_Activity__c' }; 
    CreateCaseActivity.Source__c = 'CSP - Web'; 
    let params = { documentIds: docIds, 
                   comments: this.Description_Data, 
                   rcdId: this.recordId, 
                   ipName: CreateCaseActivity 
                  }; 
                  
  saveFileUploaded(params)
  .then(result => { })
  .catch(error => { console.log('Error', error); }) 
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you show us what you have built in the lwc?

Comment: uploadFiles(docIds){
             let CreateCaseActivity = {'sobjectType': 'Case_Activity__c' };
       CreateCaseActivity.Source__c = 'CSP - Web'; let params ={
                documentIds : docIds,
                comments:this.Description_Data,
                rcdId : this.recordId,
                ipName :CreateCaseActivity
            }; saveFileUploaded(params)
                .then(result => {
                })
    
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error',error);
                  }) }

Comment: is it throwing any error? or what is the data you get at the apex end, can you share it Shashwat

Comment: What's the Apex for this? It's not clear that you're passing in a record.

Comment: On monday i will share the required code, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @CasparHarmer (JPM,sfdcfox) thanks guys , but my above code is working fine now.

Comment: Anything you did to make it work, or did it just... start working?

Comment: @CasparHarmer previously i thought of creating an instance of an object but with this declaration also it is working fine as i do not need to update the object's field value from separate apex method.